# Composer Docker image won't run at all

Tags: docker, composer-php

I'm attempting to learn how to create a Laravel Docker image by following [a tutorial on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) using WSL. Following the instructions on [the Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer), however, yields an error:

```
❯ docker run --rm --interactive --tty -v $(pwd):/app composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 94 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.4.10):     Failed to download voku/portable-ascii from dist: Could not delete /app/vendor/voku/portable-ascii/src/voku/helper:
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.4.10):

  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /app/vendor/voku/portable-ascii/src/voku/helper:


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

How can I diagnose what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the underlying problem had nothing to do with Docker at all. In fact, Composer was trying to tell me what the problem was all along, but I dismissed it as just a symptom of a deeper issue:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /app/vendor/voku/portable-ascii/src/voku/helper:
```

This message was the crux of it all. I noticed that the directory mentioned, `[...]/helper`, was empty, so I tried to remove it by hand with `rmdir`. Instead, I got a `No such file or directory` error message. I attempted many other was to kill this directory, the entire project directory with `rm -rf ~/laravel-app` from the home folder, etc. Nothing worked.

Some digging around on the internet suggested that it could be an NTFS corruption if I was running into this issue on Windows. Since I am, indeed, attempting this on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), I gave their suggested fix a try: running `chkdsk /F` in CMD/PowerShell. A reboot was necessary to complete this task, but after getting everything back up and trying those [first few tutorial steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) again, I was able to get composer to install the Laravel dependencies without a hitch.

Bottom line: If you run into this sort of issue on WSL, please try running `chkdsk /F` and reboot. You might just have a similar file system corruption.

Answer (score -1):

We have two possibilities for this error:

1 - You did not execute the command inside the directory :

```
cd ~/laravel-app
```

2 - I'm sure there is an internal proxy that is blocking the download of packages.

Comment: Hey, Yuri, thanks for the fast reply. Indeed, the command was run inside `~/laravel-app` where the `composer.json` file is. We _do_ have a very draconian firewall here at work, so it's entirely possible that it's blocking sites needed here. Is there any way to find out _which_ domains need unblocking?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with our firewall. There's a composer package that I cannot delete AT ALL. I would paste it here, but I cannot format it. Suffice to say that a package has a subdirectory in it, but every time I attempt to `rmdir` that subdirectory (which is empty), I am told "No such file or directory". Something is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the compose make the image pull firstly that's why you'll need to enable the traffic to download the related packages.

Comment: Thanks, Yuri, but the exception is that it cannot delete a folder. And I cannot delete by hand, either. I've tried for the last two hours. I cannot delete it. I *SHOULD* be able to just scrap the whole project and start from scratch, but I cannot even do that. It turns out that this problem is not related to Docker at all.

Comment: Confirmed. Since I'm doing all of this via WSL, reports online suggest that it could be an NTFS corruption and to run `chkdsk /F` to fix it. I did so, rebooted, and now the original command is working as expected.